# I want Ubutu but i have a question first

Tags: updates

I'm not new to Ubuntu my friends use it i never had a chance to use it on my own PC i'm running on a window 8 and it has no info like product keys and such it was on the box and this is a hand me down PC my question is do i need those for the installation if so how do i retrieve this info

Comment: Windows 8 will be installed in UEFI boot mode. Best to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode also:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system AND: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Ubuntu is free and you do not need a product key for it. Since you have absolutely no idea where to start, make your friends install it for you. If you don't want your friends help and want to find out on your own, google is your friend. There's a lot of information on installing ubuntu there.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need that information to boot or install ubuntu. You might need to make a windows recovery disk. I would make one if you do not have one.

You need a windows recovery disk in the event you have a problem with windows.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is, partition your hard drive and have a dual-OS just in case you don't like Ubuntu, it doesn't neede any of the product key stuff etc. just install and follow the installion guide. But back-up EVERY file you have!

Answer (score -2):

Windows 8 no longer has product keys; and several of my friends that are more into multi-booting have told me that you should wipe the disk first, then partition the disk, then install the operating systems. There are also some tools for the MBR you may need to use.

Comment: windows 8 needs a product key